# SCORM 1.2 cmi.suspend_data

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, scorm1.2

SCORM 1.2 cmi.suspend_data having limitations of storing data... can any one help me put , is there is any option  to cmi.suspend_data variable ,so i can store large data

Thanks.

Comment: How large is your data? Why do you want to store it? cmi.suspend_data can hold 4096 characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately no, most LMS's will enforce the 4096 character limitation for suspend data in SCORM 1.2. Some LMS's will allow greater lengths, but that is rare.

If you can upgrade to SCORM 2004 3rd Edition, you have additional storage up to 64000 characters in suspend data.

In SCORM 2004 4th Edition, you have the additional option of storing data in a collection called "adl.data". This collection allows you save many buckets of 64000 character data.

Answer (score 4):

You can compress cmi.suspend_data before sending to LMS and decompress when getting back.
I've used huffman coding for my project. Here is a JavaScript library: https://github.com/wilkerlucio/huffman_js